# Behat tests with PHPUnit assertions

Tags: phpunit, symfony4, behat

I had project in symfony 4.3 which uses PHPUnit Bridge 5.0, and I wanna use assert functions in functional tests (behat). In older project I used PHPUnit package and by require_once include this functions in behat Context class like this:

```
require_once __DIR__.'/../../vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/Assert/Functions.php';
```

But PHPUnit Bridge had this class by this path:

```
require_once __DIR__.'/../../bin/.phpunit/phpunit-7.5-0/src/Framework/Assert/Functions.php';
```

Instead of change this if I try run tests it's not pass with following error:

> ```
>   Fatal error: Class 'PHPUnit\Framework\Assert' not found (Behat\Testwork\Call\Exception\FatalThrowableError)
> ```

This error is caused by first use inside Functions.php class which is:

```
use PHPUnit\Framework\Assert;
```

But that class exist, because I can go to it by hand. I look in the web for some answers can be helpfull in this situation but none of these don't work. I had try use:

```
use PHPUnit_Framework_Assert as Assertions;
// Class which implement that what I need exist too in namespace PHPUnit\Framework with name Assert 
use PHPUnit\Framework\Assert as Assertions;
```

What I did wrong?? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

I'm found the solution. If someone has the same problem, just install phpunit/phpunit component and ignore warnings from PHPUnitBridge. Then use it in behat by:

```
use PHPUnit\Framework\Assert as Assertions;
```

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me:

```php
use PHPUnit\Framework\Assert;

// Then later, to check that the status is equal to 7
Assert::assertEquals(7, $this->status);
```